# What should i use to parse and unparse data like : "a:66:{s:24:"images";a:0:{} s:26:"thumbnail_image";s:0:"";:"... ?

Tags: dataformat

I'm working with ThemeFuse I found this data format. But it not looks like anything I saw before.

```
a:66:{s:24:"autotrader_slider_images";a:0:{}s:26:"autotrader_thumbnail_image";s:0:"";s:19:"seek_property_price";s:0:"";s:23:"seek_property_vat_price";s:0:"";s:21:"seek_property_mileage";s:0:"";s:25:"seek_property_engine_size";s:0:"";s:30:"seek_property_engine_power_bhp";s:0:"";s:29:"seek_property_engine_power_kw";s:0:"";s:23:"seek_property_reduction";s:1:"0";s:25:"seek_property_consumption";s:1:"0";s:20:"seek_property_origin";s:0:"";s:22:"seek_property_emission";s:13:"super emitivo";s:23:"autotrader_vehicle_type";s:3:"SUV";s:20:"autotrader_fuel_type";s:6:"Diesel";s:23:"autotrader_gearbox_type";s:9:"Automatic";s:17:"autotrader_status";s:6:"Intact";s:16:"autotrader_color";s:5:"White";s:18:"seek_property_year";s:0:"";s:26:"autotrader_enable_comments";s:5:"false";s:29:"autotrader_enable_breadcrumbs";s:4:"true";s:25:"autotrader_header_element";s:4:"none";s:23:"autotrader_header_image";s:0:"";s:23:"autotrader_header_title";s:0:"";s:24:"autotrader_select_slider";s:2:"-1";s:19:"autotrader_page_map";s:0:"";s:19:"autotrader_map_text";s:11:"We are here";s:19:"autotrader_map_zoom";s:2:"13";s:25:"autotrader_search_element";s:4:"none";s:22:"autotrader_content_top";s:0:"";s:26:"autotrader_content_bottom1";s:0:"";s:25:"autotrader_footer_element";s:4:"none";s:31:"autotrader_select_slider_footer";s:2:"-1";s:25:"autotrader_content_bottom";s:0:"";s:26:"autotrader_content_bottom2";s:0:"";s:23:"autotrader_top_ad_space";s:5:"false";s:23:"autotrader_top_ad_image";s:0:"";s:21:"autotrader_top_ad_url";s:0:"";s:25:"autotrader_top_ad_adsense";s:0:"";s:30:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_space";s:5:"false";s:25:"autotrader_bfcontent_type";s:5:"image";s:27:"autotrader_bfcontent_number";s:3:"one";s:31:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_image1";s:0:"";s:29:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_url1";s:0:"";s:33:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_adsense1";s:0:"";s:31:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_image2";s:0:"";s:29:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_url2";s:0:"";s:33:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_adsense2";s:0:"";s:31:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_image3";s:0:"";s:29:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_url3";s:0:"";s:33:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_adsense3";s:0:"";s:31:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_image4";s:0:"";s:29:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_url4";s:0:"";s:33:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_adsense4";s:0:"";s:31:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_image5";s:0:"";s:29:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_url5";s:0:"";s:33:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_adsense5";s:0:"";s:31:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_image6";s:0:"";s:29:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_url6";s:0:"";s:33:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_adsense6";s:0:"";s:31:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_image7";s:0:"";s:29:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_url7";s:0:"";s:33:"autotrader_bfcontent_ads_adsense7";s:0:"";s:21:"autotrader_hook_space";s:5:"false";s:21:"autotrader_hook_image";s:0:"";s:19:"autotrader_hook_url";s:0:"";s:23:"autotrader_hook_adsense";s:0:"";}
```

What should I use to parse and unparse this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is serialized PHP array. 
All you need to do is to unserialize it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php